# Why boot disk is not which i created

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I just created a google instance choosing centos-7 boot disk, but when I logged in to check the Linux version, the output is Debian 9.9, not centos-7.
Why does this happen?

1.I rebooted the instance
2.created a fresh one, still I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your scenario and everything is ok with my instance. Output for command 'cat /etc/centos-release' is "CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)". I think the issue is missclick, since 'Google Drawfork Debian GNU/Linux 9' image goes after 'Google Drawfork CentOS 7' in boot disk list. In your case you need just recreate your instance with proper OS image.

Comment: weird in my case though, as the boot disk list was clear with centosX and then debian.

Comment: @Manoj Can you try to recreate the instance?

Comment: sorry for the very late reply, I tried to open the cloud shell from gcp - ssh - open in browser window, and wow its Centos 7. Still I'm confused

Comment: @Manoj without instance reacreation?

Comment: yes, maybe something to do with google shell. From GCP > compute engine > VM instances > selected an instance > Activate  Cloud Shell - this shell shows Debian, but GCP > ssh > open in browser window - it's Centos